# Show speed of dd on Solaris

Tags: solaris, dd

I'm quite familiar with Linux, just now starting to learn Solaris.  To benchmark a filesystem on Linux, I might use dd:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/nas11/temp bs=1M count=1000 conv=fdatasync
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
1048576000 bytes (1.0 GB) copied, 2.96195 s, 354 MB/s
```

But on Solaris 11.4 it does not display the speed.  Is there some way to make it show the speed? I know I can run this with `time` but then I want the computer to do the math for me.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tank/ddtest bs=1000000 count=100 && sync
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
```

It seems that many "standard" tools work differently here, like `conv=fdatasync` doesn't work.

Comment: What version of Solaris? Back in the day, I would have to install the GNU tools separately; they'd have a 'g' in front of the tool name. Does `gdd` exist?

Comment: This is 7.4.  I will look into the GNU tools, thanks

Comment: [`dd` is a POSIX-standard utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html).  Features such as `conv=fdatasync` on Linux are non-standard, non-portable GNU extensions to the standard utility.  If you need to time a command, you can use [the POSIX-standard `time` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/time.html).

Comment: There was no "Solaris 7.4" release.  Do you mean Solaris 11.4 from 2018 or Solaris 7 update 4 from 1999?  You can't expect a 20-year old OS to operate the same as modern OS'es.

Comment: Sorry yes I meant 11.4

Answer (score 2):

See pipe viewer`pv`. It is a default tool on Solaris. You can use it like:

```
dd if=/dev/zero count=100000 2>/dev/null|pv|dd of=/dev/null 2>/dev/null
48.8MiB 0:00:01 [35.9MiB/s] [        <=> ]
```

Answer (score 1):

`gdd` is the version of **dd** that you want to use. On Solaris, GNU tools are installed with a 'g' in front; for example, the GNU version of tar would be called as `gtar`.